# Git keeps and old SSH key and won't let me use my new one

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have a long history with git on a particular PC, so things are quite messy.

I have a fresh SSH key that I want to use with Git for Github.
Everything is setup properly, keys are generated, added to agent and to Github.

But there's one problem.
When I try to push git tells me:

[image]

This is not my key and I deleted all the keys and credentials that was before.

What can I do to make Git forget this key so maybe it can start using the one I newly introduced?

Comment: That's the host key, not your authentication key. `ssh` is asking if *you* trust that 140.82.121.4 is actually GitHub, and not some other site masquerading as GitHub. You would verify this by getting GitHub's host key by some other trusted means, then checking if `+DiY3wvv...` matches the key you expect. If it doesn't, you would refuse to continue the connection. If it does, you can continue.

Comment: That has nothing to do with SSH keys. That's GitHub's fingerprint, and is meant to indicate possible tampering. Server fingerprints are static when established (I.e. different users see the same fingerprint, but the tampering protection means the fingerprint can change. But again, those changes apply to everyone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't SSH rejecting your key, but rather SSH asking if you accept GitHub's *host* key. You can find the current host keys at https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints.

The key in this message is listed at that page:

> SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU (Ed25519)

so assuming you trust `https://docs.github.com`, you can safely assume that SSH is connecting to the correct host and continue with the connection. If the key did not match, you would type `no` to abort the connection attempt.

Once you accept the host key, authenticating *GitHub* with you, *then* SSH will continue authenticating *you* with GitHub.

The documentation also indicates what to add to your `.ssh/known_hosts` file so you can avoid the initial confirmation when you connect the first time.

---

Sadly, most people just blindly accept whatever key the remote hosts presets, either out of laziness or because the remote host doesn't publish its host key in a secure fashion for those that *would* like to verify the presented key.